# What to publish from a new camera driver

Tags: ros, driver, camera, best-practices, camera-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
im want to write camera driver for ROS. and got some question:
ive read page about [ROS camera drivers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_drivers)
and did not understand - what type of image have to publish driver: as is image or undistored image (if the camera/camera_info was given)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11959/what-to-publish-from-a-new-camera-driver/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-11-15**:
thanks! yes - im want to write camera driver for ROS (update question)

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-11-15**:
It's not clear what you want to know. Are you asking what *you* need to publish if you write a new camera driver? Are you asking what existing drivers publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the [camera drivers wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_drivers) and the first few lines of the [image pipeline wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_pipeline), you should publish raw (distorted) images, or the closest thing your camera's API can provide. A user would almost certainly pass these to various parts of `image_pipeline` to get undistorted, debayered, etc. images for their particular application.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-11-15**:
i see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to what @Mac said, camera drivers should publish [`CameraInfo`](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) messages. The best way to do that is using the [camera_info_manager](http://ros.org/wiki/camera_info_manager) and [image_transport](http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport) packages.

The ROS drivers SIG has identified the need for a REP to fully answer this question. Meanwhile, there are other related questions on `answers.ros.org`, most with the `camera_drivers` tag.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-11-17**:
ok. Thanks!